# is it possible uploaded apk in google play is visible for selected user

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I am working on some application. this application upload in Google play store how i can set uploaded application only visible for my selected android user?

Comment: give the .apk to selected user. That's all.

Comment: thanks for fast reply u r right  but through google paly how it possible?

Comment: For specific devices it's possible. or you can do one thing just give a one key to those specific users which they will pass on Splash screen to move forward.

Comment: thanks dear but not for specific devices

Comment: if u have any other idea please share with me .

Comment: thanks all i found something . You can create a google+ group and only release that app to members of that group.https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upload app as beta version.Then you create one Google group or Google plus community,Add the peoples.Add the group into play store beta .Then publish app in play store and you will get the app URL.

Share this URL through the group.

That's all..

Answer (score 1):

Yes ,Its possible google play allows you to release your app to a few before the actual release.

**Staged rollouts**

You can release your app via a staged rollout, starting with a small percentage of your userbase and then increasing it.

[For more.](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en)

And also there are other alternatives for releasing your app. Try the following for app releases:

- [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com/android/)
- [Deploygate.](https://deploygate.com/)